RC circuit not working as intended
I am trying to plot the waveforms is following RC circuit and I am not getting the intended results:
The first voltage controlled switch (S2) is on for 4 seconds, thus charging the cap for that time and then it turns-off, immediately after that S1 gets on and I expect the capacitor to gets discharged through resistor, but when I see the waveforms, they are not as I thought they would be. Please help me understand where I am going wrong.



What do you expect to see?

@G36 , At the time S2 switches off and S1 , there is no source connected to circuit , thus the capacitor should discharge to ground through resistor. I expected following waveform.

Is your switch working with .model sw sw() at all?

But the capacitor is discharging via 100 ohm resistor. You do not see it well because for unknown reasons you have used a very large capacitor value (1F). Thus, the discharge time will be very large T = 100R*1F = 100s. And discharge will end after 500s.

Also, you need to set Vinitial to -1V for V3 and V2. Or set .model sw sw(Vh=-.5) instead. Also, S1 switch is not needed.

Yes, with this change(setting Vinitial=-1V) I am able to see expected results.. what exactly was the issue with Vinitial=0??

Because by default Vt is 0V and Vth is 0 as well. Thus, the switch will always be completely ON or OFF depending upon whether the input voltage is above or below the threshold voltage (Vt). So, we need to have a negative voltage to OFF the switch.

As @winny hinted at, you should always set your switch parameters in the .model statement instead of leaving them blank.
